# GoRouter navigation not working. Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using GoRouter to navigate my app. But I ran into the following error: When I try to navigate to the ProfilePage then nothing happens. There is not even an error message. After looking at the documentation, I seem to have done everything right, but why doesn’t the desired page open for me on click? Who knows what the problem could be?

**route_utils**

```
extension AppPageExtenstion on AppPage {
  String get toPath {
    switch (this) {
      case AppPage.home:
        return '/';
      case AppPage.profile:
        return '/profile';
      default:
        return '/';
    }
  }

  String get toName {
    switch (this) {
      case AppPage.home:
        return 'Home';
      case AppPage.profile:
        return 'Profile';
      default:
        return 'Home';
    }
  }

  String get toTitle {
    switch (this) {
      case AppPage.home:
        return 'My App';
      case AppPage.profile:
        return 'My App Profile';
      default:
        return 'My App';
    }
  }
}
```

**app_router**

```
class AppRouter {
  late final AuthProvider appService;
  GoRouter get router => _goRouter;

  AppRouter(this.appService);

  late final GoRouter _goRouter = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: appService,
    initialLocation: AppPage.home.toPath,
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.splash.toPath,
        name: AppPage.splash.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const SplashPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.home.toPath,
        name: AppPage.home.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.profile.toPath,
        name: AppPage.profile.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const ProfilePage(),
      ),
    ],
    errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(error: state.error.toString()),
    redirect: (context, state) {
      final AuthProvider appState =
          Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: true);

      final homeLocation = AppPage.home.toPath;
      final splashLocation = AppPage.splash.toPath;

      switch (appState.loggedInState) {
        case LoggedInState.loading:
          return splashLocation;
        case LoggedInState.loggedIn:
          return homeLocation;
      }
    },
  );
}
```

**main**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _appState.checkUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GoRouter goRouter =
        Provider.of<AppRouter>(context, listen: false).router;

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>.value(
      value: _appState,
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Test App',
        routeInformationParser: goRouter.routeInformationParser,
        routerDelegate: goRouter.routerDelegate,
      ),
    );
  }
```

**ui**

```
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Profile'),
          onTap: () async {
            Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
            GoRouter.of(context).push(AppPage.profile.toPath);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

**error**

[image]

> _AssertionError ('package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 274 pos 7: 'context.owner!.debugBuilding ||
> listen == false ||
> debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate': Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.
>
> This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed)
> that called Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.
>
> To fix, write: Provider.of(context, listen: false);
>
> It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget
> associated to the event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care
> about the value.

Comment: Have you tried removing appState in AppRouter? It's not doing anything. Either way you don't have a GoRouter problem. You have a Provider problem.

Comment: Yes, it's more of a problem with provider listen: true in AppRouter but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Can you get rid of that line? I don't see it referenced anywhere else. I don't recall how the redirect parameter works though.

Comment: Using appState, I get the switch state (appState.loggedInState) and then redirect the user

Comment: Do you think that the problem is that inside in AppRouter I use final AuthProvider appState =
          Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: true); ?

Comment: Yeah the error actually suggests this very solution. As far as I can tell the only place Provider is being used and being listened to is on that line.

Comment: But if I set "listen: false" then I will not be able to track state changes and navigate depending on the state

Answer (score -1):

It is probably due to

```
Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: true);
```

in the `redirect` function of the router.
Try changing to `listen:false`